# É possivel abrir activity dentro de framelayout

Tags: android, android-activity

É possivel "inflar" um activity ( nesse activity possui um recicleview) dentro de um framelayout ? se não, oque eu uso pra abrir 3 activitys diferentes, mantendo a barra de navegação em baixo como na screenshot

> public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView mTextMessage;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

}

[image: app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o que você esta procurando são "Fragments", que você pode inflar quantos quiser dentro de uma activity

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um layout com ViewPager no topo (para exibir os conteúdos e deslizar entre eles com o dedo horizontalmente) e no rodapé um TabLayout para montar a barra como da foto e também alternar o conteúdo do ViewPager. Cada conteúdo deverá ser implementado em Fragments e você vai precisar criar um Adapter para gerenciar esses Fragments no ViewPager e linkar com o TabLayout.

Nesse link tem um exemplo:
http://blog.romarconsultoria.com.br/2015/12/como-exibir-tabs-utilizando-tablayout-e.html?m=1